# HTMLのaudioタグを使って音声再生している時に、途中で音声が止まる事がある

Tags: javascript, html

HTMLでは以下のコードを書いて preload しております。

```html
<audio id="soundFile" preload="auto">
  <source
    src="xxxxxx.mp3"
    type="audio/mp3"
  />
</audio>
```

JavaScript では音声再生用ボタンを押した時に、以下のコードが実行されるようにしております。

```js
document.getElementById("soundFile").play(); // 音声再生
```

最後まで再生される場合と、最後まで再生されずに、途中で止まる場合がございます。
これは利用者側のネットワークの問題なのでしょうか？
また、こういった事に対する対処法などはございますでしょうか？

Comment: 利用しているOSやブラウザの種類・バージョンや、音声ファイルのファイルサイズ・再生時間などに関する情報も念のため記載があると回答のヒントになるかもしれません。

Comment: なるほど！ありがとうございます‍♂️

OSやブラウザの種類・バージョンについては、現在調査中なのですが、
音声ファイルのファイルサイズは、61MBで、
再生時間は、42分13秒
です。